# "Unable to cast object from ... to ... " WCF Callback

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

Since yesterday I've got a brain screwing bug. I have a WCF client and a net.tcp hosted WCF service that worked fine for weeks. Then after some minor changes, all of the sudden the service crashes on `IServiceCallBack callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallBack>()` calls, throwing a "Unable to cast..." Excpetion.
Wherever I don't need callback, everything work fine.
It's just like the service doesn't recognize the callback anymore.

I saw this could happen when VS has several version of the same assemblies in cache, so I went to `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectAssemblies` and removed all files.
With no sucess, since the bugs keep happening.

I even tried, old backups of my solution that worked fine, and now they just crashes the same way.
I'm now totally clueless about this issue.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: In your 'minor' changes, did you change any properties of objects or similar? If you make a service call via WCFTestClient, do you get the same error, a different error, or no error at all? Depending on the changes made/ your architecture, you may need to regenerate your proxies.

Comment: EDIT (to above): I now see that you've tried old backups of your solution without success, so it's unlikely that the above will solve your solution. Your problem lies in what is the same between the backup and current versions; some sort of build issue or similar. I'm not sure, someone else here might know, good luck.

Comment: Unable to cast what to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem, I actually had 2 WCF look-alike services with look-alike urls and I was using the wrong one (one withouth any callback at all).
I have no idea why my older backups seemed to work beforehand though.